# Cannot cast string to integer - ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python

I am analyzing some NBA stats. After scraping a website, I extract information such as the Home Team, Away Team, Points etc... and print them.

I would like to compute the difference between the points made by Home Team and Away Team, but since the points are of type `string`, I first need to cast them to `int`.

I tried `int(away_points)`, `float(away_points)` and `int(float(away_points))`, with no luck.
The error that I receive is `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`.

However, running the code below shows numerical values for the points:

```
Away Team: Golden State Warriors
Home Team: Brooklyn Nets
Away points: 99
Home points: 125
<class 'str'>
```

So I do not really know where the error comes from. Any help is very much appreciated.

```
for row in rows:
    if('data-stat="visitor_team_name"'):
        away_team = str(row).partition('data-stat="visitor_team_name">')[2].partition("</a")[0].partition('.html">')[2] 
        print(f"Away Team: {away_team}")
    if('data-stat="home_team_name"'):
        home_team = str(row).partition('data-stat="home_team_name">')[2].partition("</a")[0].partition('.html">')[2] 
        print(f"Home Team: {home_team}")
    if('data-stat="visitor_pts"'):
        away_pts = str(row).partition('data-stat="visitor_pts">')[2].partition("<")[0]
        print(f"Away points: {away_pts}")
    if('data-stat="home_pts"'):
        home_pts = str(row).partition('data-stat="home_pts">')[2].partition("<")[0]
        print(f"Home points: {home_pts}")

    print(type(away_pts))
    # Here I would like to convert to integers the points e.g., int(away_pts), to get the points difference 
    if(away_pts > home_pts):
        print(away_pts - home_pts)
        winner = away_team
    else:
        winner = home_team
```

Comment: That means that `away_points` is an empty string, not a number (assuming it's `away_points` causing the error).

Comment: @Carcigenicate but I am printing it, and in the example it shows to be equal to 99

Comment: You're looping, so one iteration may have a proper `away_pts`, but another may not. In one of the iterations, `away_pts` must be empty. Your parsing may be too simple to properly extract that information.

Comment: @Carcigenicate You are perfectly right. There was an iteration in which the value for `away_pts` was missing (double checked in the dataset, can confirm that), and the value that I was looking at (99) was referring to the previous iteration. 

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: When doing web-scraping, error handling and data verification are crucial. Websites often have inconsistent representations, and often have measures to thwart scraping. Always double check scraped data before using it; unless you have very high faith in your code and the consistency of the website you're scraping. Also, BeautifulSoup would likely make the parsing much easier. Manual HTML parsing is error prone and a pain.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks for the tip. I am currently exploring the concept of web scraping, which I've never touched before. I will surely explore it more deeply, because I can see that my parsing method might get me in trouble.

Comment: mind share the url where you are getting this data from?

Comment: @chitown88 basketball-reference(dot)com

Comment: You know you can easily get the data using pandas. give me the exact url of the table/data you are after

Comment: @chitown88 thanks for the comment. Full url is [link](https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2021_games-december.html)

Answer (score 1):

Reading in the table with pandas, it automatically converts the PTS columns to int.

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2021_games-december.html'
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    away_team = row['Visitor/Neutral'] 
    away_pts = row['PTS']
    home_team = row['Home/Neutral']
    home_pts = row['PTS.1']
    
    diff = (away_pts - home_pts)
    if(away_pts > home_pts):
        winner = away_team
    else:
        diff = diff*-1
        winner = home_team    
        
    print(f"\nAway Team: {away_team}")
    print(f"Home Team: {home_team}")
    print(f"Away points: {away_pts}")
    print(f"Home points: {home_pts}")
    print(f"{winner} won by {diff} points.\n")
```

**Output:

```
...

Away Team: Chicago Bulls
Home Team: Washington Wizards
Away points: 133
Home points: 130
Chicago Bulls won by 3 points.


Away Team: Philadelphia 76ers
Home Team: Orlando Magic
Away points: 116
Home points: 92
Philadelphia 76ers won by 24 points.


Away Team: Sacramento Kings
Home Team: Houston Rockets
Away points: 119
Home points: 122
Houston Rockets won by 3 points.


Away Team: New York Knicks
Home Team: Toronto Raptors
Away points: 83
Home points: 100
Toronto Raptors won by 17 points.


Away Team: New Orleans Pelicans
Home Team: Oklahoma City Thunder
Away points: 113
Home points: 80
New Orleans Pelicans won by 33 points.


Away Team: Phoenix Suns
Home Team: Utah Jazz
Away points: 106
Home points: 95
Phoenix Suns won by 11 points.
```

Comment: Very neat solution! Thank you!